# getSystemService(Context.Location_SERVICE) causes java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I'm currently creating an application with Google maps using MapFragment. In order to give the user a possibility to see location changes, I'm trying to create a LocationManager-object in the onCreate-method of the MapFragment. The problem is that the app crashes and it's caused by java.lang.NullPointerException. My initialization look like this:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)parent.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

-parent is the actitivy from which the MapFragment is executing.

My permissions look like this:

```
 <permission
        android:name="com.example.tipspromenad.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.tipspromenad.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

What can be wrong?

Hank

Comment: what is `parent`? where is it initialized

Comment: your parent is null...try to init it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess your `parent` is `NULL` at position so you got `NPE`

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)parent.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Try this way

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

in `Fragment`